# How to change the value of TextInput in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to edit the TextInput? i have already value from database `UserData.Email` (test@gmail)

```
  const [ vEmail, setUserEmail] = useState('');
  const [ UserData, setUserData] = useState({});
  const [text, onChangeText] = React.useState('');
  <Formik
      initialValues={{ 
        Email: vEmail, 
       }}
       onSubmit={(values) =>{ console.log("submit"); submitForm(values)}}
    >
    {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values, errors, isValid,touched,setFieldValue }) => (
<View style={formStyles.SectionStyle}>
  <TextInput
    name="Email"
    value={UserData.Email || ''}
    style={formStyles.inputStyle}
    underlineColorAndroid="#f000"
    placeholderTextColor="#8b9cb5"
    keyboardType="email-address"
    onChangeText={handleChange('Email')}

  />
  
</View>
)
```

UPDATE this is how i fetch record from my database using api

```
  const getProfile = async(token) =>{
    let jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
    jsonValue = JSON.parse(jsonValue);
    setProfile(jsonValue);
    console.log(config.API_URL + '/users/'+ jsonValue.userId)
    fetch(config.API_URL + '/users/'+ jsonValue.userId, {

      method: 'GET',
      //body: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
      headers: {
        //Header Defination
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
    .then((response) =>  response.json().then(data=>({status:response.status, body:data})) )
    .then((response) => {
    console.log("User information = ",response);
    if(response.status==200)
        {
          if(response.body.length > 0)
          {         

            let _UserData = {};
            setUserData(response.body[0]);
            setUserEmail(decodeURI(response.body[0].Email))
           

          }else{
            setErrortext(response.body.msg);
            setPreventSubmit(true);
          }
        }else{
          setErrortext(response.body.msg);
          setPreventSubmit(true);
        };
      })
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Formik here you dont have to maintain a component level state for email here.

You can do like below which will use the state of Formik and can get that when using the handleSubmit,
Sample code would be like below

```
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    Email: 'test1@gmail.com',
  }}
  onSubmit={(values) => {
    console.log('submit');
    alert(values.Email);
  }}>
  {({
    handleChange,
    handleBlur,
    handleSubmit,
    values,
    errors,
    isValid,
    touched,
    setFieldValue,
  }) => (
    <View style={formStyles.SectionStyle}>
      <TextInput
        name="Email"
        value={values['Email']}
        style={formStyles.inputStyle}
        underlineColorAndroid="#f000"
        placeholderTextColor="#8b9cb5"
        keyboardType="email-address"
        onChangeText={handleChange('Email')}
      />
      <Button title="Submit" onPress={handleSubmit}/>
    </View>
  )}
</Formik>
```

Instead of the hardcoded value for initial value, you can use your email address that you retrieve from your database (or API)

You can check the below demo
https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/d05b51

Comment: `initialValues={{ Email: UserData.Email,}}` i get no value

Comment: you can use your vEmail, userData is empty right ?

Comment: I've posted my code fetching data from api sir

Comment: `userData.Email` is not empty, because i tried in this in my value={userData.Email} and it print to the browser

Comment: ok i get the issue, the component is not re rendered when userData is set, better move the data loading part to parent and pass as a prop to this component

Comment: srry , but i dont understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231497/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-user14823468).

Answer (score 0):

you are passing static value to the textInput. it should be dynamic

```
const [ vEmail, setUserEmail] = useState('');
const [ UserData, setUserData] = useState({});
const [text, onChangeText] = React.useState('');
<Formik
  initialValues={{ 
    Email: vEmail, 
   }}
   onSubmit={(values) =>{ console.log("submit"); submitForm(values)}}
>
{({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values, errors, 
isValid,touched,setFieldValue }) => (
<View style={formStyles.SectionStyle}>
<TextInput
  name="Email"
  value={vEmail}
  style={formStyles.inputStyle}
  underlineColorAndroid="#f000"
  placeholderTextColor="#8b9cb5"
  keyboardType="email-address"
  onChangeText={handleChange('Email')}

/>

</View>
)
```

vEmail should contain the email address fetched from database. Onchange also should set email using setUserEmail in the vEmail

Comment: I've tried this method,
for example, the data from the database can be seen first in Text Input and then when I click on TextInput I can edit

Answer (score 0):

```
const [ vEmail, setUserEmail] = useState('');
const [ UserData, setUserData] = useState({});
const [text, onChangeText] = React.useState('');
<Formik
  initialValues={{ 
    Email: vEmail, 
   }}
   onSubmit={(values) =>{ console.log("submit"); submitForm(values)}}
>
   {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values, errors, 
   isValid,touched,setFieldValue }) => (
   <View style={formStyles.SectionStyle}>
   <TextInput
    name="Email"
    value={UserData.Email || ''} // this state needs to be update on change
    style={formStyles.inputStyle}
    underlineColorAndroid="#f000"
    placeholderTextColor="#8b9cb5"
    keyboardType="email-address"
    onChangeText={handleChange('Email')} // this is wrong here
  />  
  </View>
```

Your `useState` exists on this component. So, you should update your state in this component itself on the change of `TextInput`.

Your `onChangeText` should look, like this

```
onChangeText={(text)=>handleChange(text)}
or
onChangeText={handleChange}
```

In both ways, you will get the text value in `handleChange` as an argument, but you are using TextInput's value from `UserData.Email`. So, you should be updating that field in `handleChange` means your `handleChange` should exist in this component only.

Hope you are getting my point.

Comment: I change my `onChangeText={handleChange('Email')` into  onChangeText={handleChange} but same, I cant edit the TextInput

Comment: You can't because your `handleChange` is coming as an argument, and you are using a state defined here, so eventually, you are not updating that state field

Comment: so, what should i do?

Comment: First, you have to decide how your code flow should be. Like, what is the need for `handleChange` coming from the argument. If no need found, you can define your `handleChange` here and update `Userdata.Email` value in that `handleChange`